# Matplotlib plt.text automatically shift the position of text region when it is close to the image border?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I noticed that when the text area is too big, matplotlib automatically shift the position of the text region when I use `plt.text` to place **rotated text regions**, even if I explicitly set horizontal alignment to be left and vertical alignment to be top.

The code looks like this:

```
aa = plt.text(axis_lim/20.,axis_lim/2., text, ha='left', va = 'top',
              fontproperties = myf, rotation = ro, wrap=True)
```

[image]

Any idea to avoid this automatic shifting?

Answer (score 0):

`plt` seems to have some automatic alignment if I set `warp` to be true. Even if it is set to be `false`, the calculated rotated corners are still not correct. I switched to use PIL default rotation functions to rotate the image instead: `htext_layer.rotate(48,center=(min_x, min_y),fillcolor='white')`